# displaying a group once in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data like this :

```
1   TC1 PASS
2   TC2 FAIL
3   TC3 INCONC
4   TC1 FAIL
5   TC21    FAIL
6   TC4 PASS
7   TC3 PASS
8   TC2 FAIL
9   TC1 TIMEOUT
10  TC21    FAIL
```

If I try the below code :

```
<?php

   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pop") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("jpd") or die(mysql_error());
   $oustanding_fails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SELECT_PASS ") or die(mysql_error());  

   $resultSetArray = array();
   $platform;

   while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $oustanding_fails )) {
     if(trim($row1['TESTCASE']) <> trim($platform))   {
       echo $row1['TESTCASE']."-"; 
       $platform = $row1['TESTCASE'];
     }

     echo $row1['RESULT'] ."<br>";
} ?>
```

...to get a result like this :

```
TC1
   PASS
   FAIL
   TIMEOUT
TC2
   FAIL
   FAIL
TC3
   INCONC
   PASS
TC4
   PASS
```

...and so on. I am unable to get the result I want `LIKE ABOVE` - any ideas where exactly I am making mistake?

Comment: What output would you like to get? Are you only trying to show each of the same status only once?

Comment: I want to show all the TESTCASES just once, I can use group by in SQL but since I want all the data pertaining to that TESTCASES I though it would be more sensible to show this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your sql to:

```
SELECT * FROM SELECT_PASS ORDER BY TESTCASE
```

Comment: Can you please explain me why this worked? I really did not think that ordering will give me the result I want. Is there any debugger for any SQL database to actually see how it is fetching the results and the whole process till it  displays the results? or any PHP debugger ?

Comment: Ordering the results is very common across any database.  You don't need a debugger.  Just use something like MySQLWorkbench to create SQL statements and evaluate the results without needing to include PHP.  Then when you are satisfied with the SQL, paste it into your PHP code.